# Replace JSON objects with plain arrays to reduce network overhead expenses

Tags: javascript, json, performance, gmail, network-protocols

Currently for RIA client-server communication I'm using JSON over HTTP. But payload is only about 20-30% of all data volume.

So **I'd like replace JSON objects with something like gmail protocol**:

```
)]}'

89
[["v","xAsy6ax_v6o.en.","8","dd1ee0840f5f7b2d"]
,["di",569,,,,,[]
,[]
,,,[]
,[]
,[]
]
]
2691
[["ld",[["^ig",0,-1,-1,2,0,"l",,0,75,1,,1]
,["^i",0,-1,-1,2,0,"l",,0,2,1,,0]
,["^t",-1,-1,-1,2,0,"l",,0,5,1,,1]
,["^io_im",38,-1,-1,2,0,"l",,0,49,1,,1]
]
,[["[Imap]/Drafts",0,11,0,0,0,"l",,0,44,1,0,1,,,,0]
,["[Imap]/Sent",0,1438,0,0,0,"l",,0,43,1,0,1,,,,0]
,["[Imap]/Trash",0,742,0,0,0,"l",,0,42,1,0,1,,,,0]
```

As you can see - **this king of protocol is much more efficient for network transfer**. By my own calculation - it can **reduce volume of data from 3 to 5 times**.

But it's more difficult to process. I'm **looking for some library** that can using pre-stored structures **parse info and convert such arrays to normal objects**.

**Performance of parsing of course is very important.**

As I understand - this should be something like protobuf, but for JS. **Do you know any proper lib**?

Comment: I think you should look into compression algorithms, then compress on the sender's side and uncompress on the receiver's

Comment: You could adapt this NodeJS script to convert JSON to CSV: https://github.com/yelkhatib/JSON-to-CSV